# When I add and array to an object using prototype in Javascript, all instances of the object act like they're sharing one array

Tags: javascript, inheritance, object, prototype-programming

I'm using a bit of code that I found on the web to manufacture objects.  It allows me to organize objects into namespaces, and keeps my code pretty readable.

```
var TEST = {};

//The next two lines is the stuff that I found on the web. I think I 
//basically understand what's going on here, but maybe I'm implementing it 
//incorrectly?
TEST.testObj = function () { this.initialize.apply(this, arguments); };
TEST.testObj.prototype = {

    a: null,
    b: [],

    initialize: function(a) {

        this.a = a;
        this.b[0] = a;
    }

}


t1 = new TEST.testObj(1);
t2 = new TEST.testObj(2);

alert(t1.a + ', ' + t2.a);
alert(t1.b + ', ' + t2.b);
```

So, basically t1.a, a primitive, retains it's value when t2 is instantiated. But t1.b changes. It seems like both instances are simply referencing a single array, but creating unique primitives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fuzzy about prototype inheritance, make sure you read up on it - it will help you reason about this problem. In essence, an object inherits all properties of its prototype, but an object's own properties has higher precedence than those of its prototype. In your example, `TEST.testObj.prototype` is the prototype of both `t1` and `t2`. Thus, both `t1` and `t2` inherit its properties.

When the `Test.testObj` constructor is called, it then calls the `initialize` method, which then sets the object's `a` property to the passed-in parameter. This operation will create an `a` property on the object itself (it's *own* property), this will override the inherited `a` property on `Test.testObj.prototype`. Thus, each time a constructor is called, the new object will get its own `a` property.

The second statement in `initialize`

```
this.b[0] = a;
```

is different in nature. It first looks up property `b` on the object. Since it is not found on the object itself, it goes up to its prototype `Test.testObject.prototype` and finds it there. Now, having a handle on the array object, it then modifies its zeroth element. As you can see, each time the constructor gets called, this same array will be modified.

Comment: Thanks, Toby, this helps a lot. I moved the array declaration into the initialize method and that cleared it up. I've been trying to get a better handle on inheritance in JavaScript, but I guess it's still a little hazy. Is there anything you can point me in the direction of to read?

Comment: I wrote an article a while back http://tobyho.com/2010/11/22/javascript-constructors-and/, also this http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html is quite good as well. If you are looking for a book, I recommend Javascript the Good Parts.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating this array for the prototype of these.

That's any instance of this prototype shares the same object properties' values.

In order to avoid this situation, **you'll design properties/fields in methods if these are constant or shared values**. Think about them as static members in other languages.

Otherwise, set properties/fields for the particular instance:

```
var some = new TEST.testObj();
some.b = [];
```

...so *b* value won't be shared across all *testObj* instances.

Comment: I've developed an open source JavaScript library that can aid you in OOP and it's available in Codeplex:

- http://joopl.codeplex.com